# Disposing a vb6 object - A surprising problem

Tags: vb6

I have "invented" a linked-list technique in vb6 by placing a pointer inside the object:

```
Class FooBar:
Public ptr As FooBar
```

Now I just hold a pointer to the head of the list, inside `Head.ptr` points to the next object, `Head.ptr.ptr` points to the next object, etc.

When I want to destroy the list I just use `Set Head = Nothing`, this result in clearing Head.ptr, which in turn triggers clearing Head.ptr.ptr etc, resulting in an empty list (I actually checked it by placing a break-point in the Class_Terminate event).

This works nice and neat, until I have like 10,000 objects in the list. Now the line `Set Head = Nothing` results in "Out of stack memory" error, after which an IDE crash.

Turns out, vb6 is clearing the object recursively (it happens even if I don't have the Class_Terminate event).

So I thought I should destroy the list "manually", with some sort of loop. but I couldn't figure out a way to do so, as using a pointer in the loop and setting it to Nothing does... nothing since it AddRef to the object!

What should I do???

Comment: *"What should I do?"* Not abusing the language like this would be a start. Use an array or a collection. (Or a conventional linked list with an explicit disposal routine.)

Comment: How exactly does setting Head = nothing "trigger" the cascading nothing-setting of all the child ptrs? I can't see what mechanism would cause that to occur automatically.

Comment: You probably should post some more code so we can really evaluate what is goingon.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs: Whenever the last reference to an object is cleared, the object is removed. So, when I remove the object "Head", it is no longer points to Head.ptr object, so Head.ptr must also be removed, and so on. As I said, I have confirmed it with a break-point. There is literally no other code relevant to the subject. I just initialize new objects and assign the last .ptr to them.

Comment: Ok, but that isn't necessarily done recursively, though it must be done iteratively. If VB6 really is doing it recursively and it leads to a stack error I find that quite surprising.  What is the size of your linked list when this happens?

Comment: Recursion is actually the natural way.

It basically walks through the object members and call the appropriate destructor for that member.

If, for example, it encountered a string member - it calls the internal string destructor, for an array member - it will erase the array, and for an object, it will call the object's Release() method, which repeats this process for that object, thus a recursion is formed.

Comment: Each class instance destructor is releasing the resources that instance has allocated.  Which calls those resources' destructors. That those subsequent destructors are instances of the same class does not make this recursion. The same problem would manifest if there were 10,000 different classes instantiated and linked together. Problem is there isn't enough stack space to make 10,000 (or so) subroutine (destructor) calls deep. This is another way to describe what @markbertenshaw describes in his answer. A collection is almost certainly a better solution and would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

I Finally worked out a way to manually destroy the list.

A somewhat tricky but working solution.

I first add a small method to the class that clears the internal pointer without removing the object.

```
Class FooBar:
Public ptr As FooBar

Public Function SafeRemove() As FooBar
Set SafeRemove = ptr
Set ptr = Nothing
End Function
```

In a module:

```
Sub ClearList()
While Head Is Nothing = False
    Set Head = Head.SafeRemove
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Neat! So `Set Head = Head.SafeRemove` releases `Head` but keeps `ptr` still alive not to recurse the `Terminate` event.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand why you get a stack overflow. You are implicitly calling the Release() method of the IUnknown interface, which them calls an internal VB destroy method, which clears down all internal state, including the variable which points to the next item, which then calls Release(), etc., etc.

To get around the stack overflow problem, you would be better off implementing a doubly linked list, and always saving a pointer to the end of the list. But then you would now have the problem of circular references, and nothing would clear down unless you had a specific disposal method.

You might as well use the VBA.Collection object, which I have been told (in the book Hardcore Visual Basic *is* a doubly linked list internally).

Comment: Doubly linked list accomplish nothing in this case, if anything - it worsen it even more...

Comment: A collection is a good alternative. But there must be a solution to this problem, no?

Comment: A collection is less flexible than a low-level c-style linked list. For example: it is not easily sorted.

Comment: The standard collection object may not be easily sortable, but you can create a custom collection that is easily sortable. Although the terminology is different, a custom collection in VB6 is essentially creating a strongly typed collection that inherits and extends the standard collection object.